# Using a coordinatorlayout to collapse a full screen imageview and replace it with viewpager with headers

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-coordinatorlayout

I started playing around with coordinatoralyout and I'm trying to achieve the behavior on the attached image, I want a background image to be on full screen size and upon a scroll I want some textviews to dissapear and some to stick as parts of a viewpager (rather then a toolbarlayout) any guidance on how can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Is it alright if you can see the tabs in the first state ? Or you absolutely want to hide them ?

Comment: Have you looked new design support widget BottomSheet ... i think you can achive this using BottomSheet ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **layout_behavior** to handle the strings which you want to be disappear upon scroll. Customise your view behaviour using **CoordinatorLayout.Behavior**

**ViewBehavior.java**

```
public class ViewBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<RelativeLayout> {

private Context mContext;

public ViewBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, RelativeLayout child, View dependency) {
    return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
}

@Override
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, RelativeLayout child, View dependency) {
    child.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
    int maxScroll = ((AppBarLayout) dependency).getTotalScrollRange();
    float percentage = Math.abs(dependency.getY()) / (float) maxScroll;
    float childPosition = dependency.getHeight()
            + dependency.getY()
            - child.getMeasuredHeight()
            - (getToolbarHeight() - child.getMeasuredHeight()) * percentage / 2;

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    child.setLayoutParams(lp);

    child.setY(childPosition);
    return true;
}

public int getToolbarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (mContext.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
        result = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

In layout xml, set your custom view behaviour as a **app:layout_behavior** in the view you want to handle.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
            app:pstsTextAllCaps="true" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="com.stacktest.ViewBehavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Text-1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Text-2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Text-3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:text="Text-4" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Finally, use the layout and create ViewPager and Tabs in your Activity class.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ((CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar)).setTitle(" ");

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabsStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabsStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);
}

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2" };

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TestFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
}
```

Add following extra dependency in **build.gradle** along with appcompat and support library.

- com.android.support:design:23.2.1
- com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1 (for ViewPager tabs)

Comment: That is *almost* exactly what I need!
I saw the behavior class on some tutorial I've read\seen since posting this but I can't really apply it to the image. in my question the green color should be the image (i.e scale=fitXY) and I want to shrink it to "act" as a barlayout - do you have a clue for how can I chieve that?

Comment: Add image to the ImageView(android:src) with scaleType=fitXY. Remove **<item ame="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>** from values-21/styles.xml

Answer (score 1):

As I am not sure if you want a particular or a general solution, I am going to give you my solution for your particular question. The key is to work with `scrollFlags` and `collapseMode`. If you *really* want to hide the tabs when the appBar is expanded, you can play with visibility.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="375dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="textView1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="textView2"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/mToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="textView3"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="textView4"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/tab_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: Thanks, however I need the imageview to have a match_parent on it's highet so it'll be the background of the CollapsingToolbarLayout.
essentialy I need the imageview to have a touch event in which it acts like the bottom part of a collapingtoolbarlayout (the one's responsible for minifying the upper barlayout)

Comment: But for the CollapsingToolbarLayout you will need to set a maximum height. You can set match_parent on the imageview if you want, but then you'll have to set a height to your imageView's containing layout. For the touch event, just add a clickListener to your image and collapse the toolbar programatically like so `appBarLayout.setExpanded(true/false)`

Comment: The thing is I want to get something similar to here - 
http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

only with the background imageview to be full screen, and still let it be swipeable. placing an onclicklistener will not solve my problem since it does not answer my question of how to ahieve this...